# Difference between self.variableName and _variableName

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, dealloc

I have code like this:

## MyClass.h

```
@interface MyClass : CCLayer {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *spriteName;  //retain count = 1
@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomClass *customVariable; //retain count = 1

@end
```

## MyClass.m

```
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize spriteName;
@synthesize customVariable;

//rough init method
-(void)init 
{
    self.spriteName = [CCSprite spriteWithFileName:@"a.png"]; //retain count = same
    self.customVariable = [[CustomClass alloc] init]; //retain count = 2
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [self.spriteName release]; //retain count = 0
    self.spriteName = nil;

    [self.customVariable release]; //retain count = 1?
    self.customVariable = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I have some questions about this:

1) I have a CCSprite which I've made into a property, however when I assigned it to `[CCSprite spriteWithFileName:@"a.png"]`, it is an autoreleased object. But because I have `@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *spriteName`, I have to release it yes?

2) For my customVariable, I seem to get an error when I release it in the manner above, but when I changed them to underscores, `[_customVariable release]; _customVariable = nil`, I get no error. Why is this and what is the difference between the two?

3) Am I releasing these objects right? I have commented in the retain count which I think I'm having trouble understanding. I know the basic if there's an alloc or retain then I should +1 but I'm confused when it comes to properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the full deal with these iVars goes as follows. The compiler silently treats your code like this:

```
@interface MyClass : CCLayer {
    CCSprite *_spriteName;
}

@property (nonatomic,readwrite, retain) CCSprite *spriteName;  //retain count = 1

@end

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize spriteName=_spriteName;

@end
```

in your code, the 'readwrite' and the iVar's name are implicit (_spriteName), and the compiler generates the appropriate code. You could however have an iVar with a different name to point to the actual CCSprite. Using the self.spriteName semantic, the compiler converts that (auto-generates) the code under the hood. In you example the compiler has generated a setter and a getter for 'self.spriteName' (synthesized) as follows:

```
-(void) setSpriteName:(CCSprite*) theSpriteName {
   // this setter can be quite tricky depending on the @property clause 
   // but for this example, a simplified setter :

    [_spriteName autorelease];  
    _spriteName = [theSpriteName retain]; 

}
-(CCSprite*) spriteName {
    return _spriteName;
}
```

so when you use self.spriteName , depending on the context (lhs or rhs), the appropriate 'hidden' routine is called. So the line

```
self.spriteName = [CCSprite spriteWithFileName:@"a.png"];
```

actually invokes the generated setter above (setSpriteName). Conversely

```
CCSprite *tempSprite = self.spriteName;
```

invokes the generated getter. You are always free to use the 'underlying' iVar.

```
CCSprite *otherTempSprite = _spriteName; // exactly the same.
```

be very cautious however about changing _spriteName's content or altering its life cycle, as you could accidentally create either a leak or a zombie, until you fully understand the internals. In dealloc, use

```
[_spriteName release]; // in dealloc, release immediately.
```

or

```
self.spriteName=nil;   // will invoke the setter above, and the 
                       //   actual release could be delayed
```

So finally, back to your problem with customVariable. Your code actually becomes

```
[_customVariable release];  // retain count is 0 !!! 
[self setCustomVariable:nil]; 

which when called will execute :

[_customVariable autorelease]; // bad access : message sent to a deallocated variable 
_customVariable=nil;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! So everytime self.object is called it'll autorelease the old object and retain the new one? I never knew that. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: actually every time self.object=something (the setter) will release the old and retain the new, when your property is 'retain'. When your property is 'assign' there will be no releasing and no retaining. 'retain' just takes ownership of the object, so that it would not be deallocated elsewhere while you need it.

Comment: One more question though, when I have self.customVariable = [[CustomClass alloc] init], I alloc space for the variable and then in the setter method it's retained...doesn't this mean it's being retained twice?

Comment: Yes. I tend to create 'autorelease' ctors, a-la-cocos. So i would have a constructor [CustomClass customClassWithParameters:whatever] that will return a [[[CustomClass alloc] init] autorelease] object, just because i'm lazy :). Otherwise, you would (if not using ARC) do self.customVariable=[[[CustomClass alloc] init] autorelease]. So when you do [_customVariable release] in the dealloc, the underlying object will eventually be released by the autorelease pool. Otherwise, it is leaked.